# How to upgrade zeromq 2.2 to 3.2 efficiently

Tags: zeromq

I would like to upgrade my version of zeromq 2.2 to zeromq 3.2. I thought it will be easy , but after installing the new version correctly, I checked with this command ( zmq.zmq_version() ). and it's still the 2.2 version.

I don't know why it doesn't take effect,I did it like this:
1. I download zeromq 3.2 
2. I install it with these commands: ./configure,sudo make,sudo make install.

Could anyone help on this please ?

Comment: how did you install pyzmq?  You need to recompile and reinstall pyzmq after doing a major upgrade of libzmq.

Comment: You might want to `sudo apt-get remove libzmq1 libzmq-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language are you working in? It sounds like the language binding is using its own copy of libzmq somewhere. Also, "sudo ldconfig" after installing, just for certainty.

Comment: I use python language, and my i work on ubuntu 12.04, I really need to migrate toward the new version